# Weather App- Python

Tags: python, beginner, tkinter

This is my very basic Weather App. Would appreciate your opinion mainly about style, writing code etc. I know there is not much functionality to this app, but I have created it just to practice and to share with you guys so you could possibly point weak points I need to focus on as a programmer. As I am learning mainly from materials I find online, the opinion of professionals will be much appreciated so I can go in the right direction.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests, json, os
from tkinter import StringVar, ttk
from pathlib import Path


class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, database: object, icons: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._db = database
        self._icons = icons
 
        self.enter_city()
        self.update_vars()
        self.labels()
        self.weather_img()
        # auto update function, 'while typing' style    
        self.update_data()
        
        self.geometry('350x450')
        self.title('Weather App')
        self.iconbitmap(f'{icons}\\icon.ico')


    def weather_img(self) -> None:
        # set weather image
        self.icon = StringVar()
        self.icon.set(WeatherData.get_icon_code(self.weather))
        # weather icon path
        weather_icon = Path(f'{icons}\\{self.icon.get()}.png')
        # ensure during changing city when icon code not availabe there is no error, refresh icon on the screen
        if weather_icon.is_file():
            self.weather_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=f'{icons}\\{self.icon.get()}.png')
        else:
            self.weather_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=f'{icons}\\refresh.png')
        self.image_lbl = ttk.Label(self, image=self.weather_image)
        self.image_lbl.place(x=45, y=35)            


    def enter_city(self) -> None:
        # City entry
        self.city_ent = ttk.Entry(self, justify='center', width=50)
        self.city_ent.place(x=20, y=10)
        self.city_var = StringVar(value='Warsaw')


    def update_vars(self) -> None:
        # Get weather data for City
        self.weather = WeatherData.get_weather(self._db, self.city_var.get())
        
        # set vars for auto update
        self.temp = StringVar()
        self.temp.set(WeatherData.get_temp(self.weather))
        self.wind = StringVar()
        self.wind.set(WeatherData.get_wind_direction(self.weather))
        self.prediction = StringVar()
        self.prediction.set(WeatherData.get_predicted_weather(self.weather))


    def labels(self) -> None:
        self.city_lbl = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.city_var, width=35, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), anchor='center')
        self.city_lbl.place(x=10, y=290)
        self.city_ent.configure(textvariable=self.city_var)

        self.temp_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text='Temperature:', font=('Helvetica', 11))
        self.temp_lbl.place(x=10, y=330)

        self.wind_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text='Wind direction:', font=('Helvetica', 11))
        self.wind_lbl.place(x=10, y=360)

        self.prediction_lbl = ttk.Label(self, text='Predicted weather:', font=('Helvetica', 11))
        self.prediction_lbl.place(x=10, y=390)

        self.temp_val_lbl = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.temp, font=('Helvetica', 11))
        self.temp_val_lbl.place(x=220, y=330)
        
        self.wind_val_lbl = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.wind, font=('Helvetica', 11))
        self.wind_val_lbl.place(x=220, y=360)

        self.prediction_val_lbl = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.prediction, font=('Helvetica', 11))
        self.prediction_val_lbl.place(x=220, y=390)
        
        
    def update_data(self) -> None:
        self.weather = WeatherData.get_weather(self._db, self.city_var.get())
        self.temp.set(WeatherData.get_temp(self.weather))
        self.wind.set(WeatherData.get_wind_direction(self.weather))
        self.prediction.set(WeatherData.get_predicted_weather(self.weather))
        # destroy icon label, so new one won't be on top of old one
        self.image_lbl.destroy()
        # refresh icon label
        self.weather_img()
        self.after(1000, self.update_data)



class WeatherData:
    def __init__(self, key: str) -> None:
        self._key = key

    # excepting KeyError for autoupdate. App won't stop working while typing new city name

    def get_weather(self, city: str) -> list:
        url = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&units=metric&appid={self._key}'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        return data


    def get_temp(data: list) -> str:
        try:
            celsius = data['main']['temp']
            return str(round(celsius))
        except KeyError:
            pass


    def get_predicted_weather(data: list) -> str:
        try:    
            sky = data['weather']
            for item in sky:
                for key, value in item.items():
                    if key == 'main':
                        return str(value)
        except KeyError:
            pass


    def get_wind_direction(data: list) -> str:
        try:    
            wind = data['wind']['deg']
            if wind == 0:
                return 'North'
            elif wind > 0 and wind < 90:
                return 'North East'
            elif wind == 90:
                return 'East'
            elif wind > 90 and wind < 180:
                return 'South East'
            elif wind == 180:
                return 'South'
            elif wind > 180 and wind < 270:
                return 'South West'
            elif wind == 270:
                return 'West'
            else:
                return 'North West'
        except KeyError:
            pass


    # get icon code to display right weather icon
    def get_icon_code(data: list) -> str:
        try:    
            info = data['weather']
            for item in info:
                for key, value in item.items():
                    if key == 'icon':
                        return value
        except KeyError:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    
    # Free API key
    with open(f'{_current_path}\\settings\\apiconfig.json', 'r') as f:
        api_file = json.load(f)
        for key, value in api_file.items():
            if key == 'key':
                _api_key = value
    
    # icons folder
    icons = f'{_current_path}\\icons'
    
    db = WeatherData(_api_key)
    Window(db, icons).mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

- Don't hint `database` as an `object`; hint it as a `WeatherData`. To resolve the missing  symbol, move `Window` below `WeatherData`. If for whatever reason you weren't able to do that, you could also hint it in string syntax, i.e. `'WeatherData'`.
- Avoid inheriting from `tk.Tk` and instead put it in a member variable ("has-a", not "is-a"). I say this because you don't override any of the parent functions and you don't reference any of its member variables from what I see.
- Rather than hard-coding backslashes in your paths, make `icons` a `pathlib.Path`, and use the `/` operator to get to `icon.ico`
- `self.icon` isn't referenced outside of `weather_img` so it doesn't need to be a member variable; similar for the member variables `weather_image`, `city_lbl`, etc.
- Repeated expressions like this:

```
    ttk.Label(self, text='Temperature:', font=('Helvetica', 11))
```

can be reduced by

```
label = partial(ttk.Label, self, font=('Helvetica', 11))

self.temp_lbl = label(text='Temperature:')
# etc.
```

- It's a good idea to represent `WeatherData` as a class, but not such a good idea to have most of its member functions accept a `data` parameter. If you move `get_weather` outside of the class and pass its result to `WeatherData`'s constructor. Save it to a member variable. Modify `get_temp` to have a `self` parameter, no `data` parameter, and use its member variable; similar with other functions. This way, `WeatherData` is actually meaningful as a class, and is effectively immutable.
- Do not format your query parameters into your URL. Pass them in the `params` dict argument to `get()`.
- Use the return value of `get`, the response, in a `with`.
- Call `response.raise_for_status()`.
- Since you have exception handling around `data['main']['temp']`, the return type can't be `str`, but instead `Optional[str]`. Similar for other functions.
- It's good that you have a main guard, but it's not enough. All of those variables are still in global scope. Make a `main` function and call it from your main guard.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another few things learnt. As to Optional[str] always thought if there is exception, that doesn't count as it's excepted, so it would be only str, learning something everyday. Thank you for your time to review it, means and helps a lot.

Comment: It's not `Optional` because there's an exception - it's `Optional` because you _catch_ the exception and then implicitly return `None`. If you were to let the exception fall through, then the hint would remain `str`.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: I have two questions about the suggestion to reduce repeated expressions by `partial()`: (1) Just to clarify, it's `partial()` from the `functools` module, right? (2) Is this replacement commonly considered to be good style? I've never used `partial()` before, so I'm not experienced with its use cases. But at first glance, it somewhat obscures that `label()` creates GUI elements, especially if you miss the place where it has been defined. I'd have guessed that the explicit `ttk.Label()` was to be preferred here. So, perhaps you could elaborate a bit why `partial()` is the better choice?

Comment: @Schmuddi 1. correct; 2. It isn't strictly a better choice, but it eliminates a lot of repeated code. Another alternative is to make a dedicated class method that does an equivalent label construction. A better name such as `make_label` could be used to address your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

- Destroying and re-creating the entire icon label feels like an awkward solution. Isn't it possible to keep the label as it is and only replace its image? I believe something like `self.image_lbl.configure(image=self.weather_image)` might do that

  - I'm also wondering if we actually need to do that manually. We might be able to use `self.icon.trace_add` to automatically update the icon when that variable changes. This might look a bit like so:

```py
def enter_city(self) -> None:
    self.icon = StringVar()

    def icon_change_callback(_: str, _name: str, _mode: str):
        icon_path = Path(self._icons, f"{self.icon.get()}.png")

        if icon_path.is_file():
            self.weather_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_path)
        else:
            self.weather_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=Path(self._icons, "refresh.png"))

        self.image_lbl.configure(image=self.weather_image)

    self.icon.trace_add("write", icon_change_callback)

    self.image_lbl = ttk.Label(self)
    self.image_lbl.place(x=45, y=35)
```

- That still ends up re-loading the entire icon file every second, though. That's not ideal. It'd probably be better to keep the `PhotoImage`s around somewhere so we can look them up without having to bother wish disk I/O
- We might be able to use callbacks with `self.city_var` as well - that might let us update right away when the variable gets updated, while not having to update *every* second the rest of the time. The weather doesn't usually change *that* fast after all
- Why is `WeatherData` a class anyway? Most of the methods don't interact with the class at all, so they could just as easily be standalone functions. The only exception is `get_weather`, but if we only have one method, we usually aren't any better off by using a class than we'd be if we'd just used a function
- Those loops in `get_icon_code` and `get_predicted_weather` feel awkward. It seems to me like they can be simplified to `data['weather'][0]['main']` - am I missing something?

  - If we can do that, most of those helper functions turn into one-liners that just get data from a known location in a dict. As much as I like functions, I'm not sure we actually need to keep those
- `get_wind_direction` feels like it has two jobs - getting a wind angle from an API result and turning an angle into a compass direction. Those aren't *that* closely related, and kind of feel like they could belong in two different functions
- Similarly, `update_vars` is responsible for creating variables, while `update_data` is clearly responsible for updating the program's state. So I'd say we could get rid of the updating part of `update_vars`, maybe rename it to `create_vars` or something
- Speaking of names, all of `Window`'s methods exist to perform actions, and should probably be named after the actions they perform. `labels` and `weather_img` feel less descriptive than `create_labels` and `create_weather_image`. And while `enter_city` and `update_vars` do describe actions, those are not the actions those functions perform - `enter_city` creates an entry field, and as mentioned `update_vars` doesn't update existing variables but instead creates new ones
- The `data` parameters of `WeatherData`'s methods all seem to have the wrong type - the type hints say `list`, but they're `dict`s

  - Those functions also claim to always return `str`, but they may return `None`. Either allow them to raise those exceptions instead of swallowing them, change the return type to `typing.Optional[str]`, or make them return some kind of `str` even if the lookup fails
- `weather_img` depends on the global variable `icons`, which I don't think we want. We already save that variable as `self._icons` during `__init__`, so I see no reason not to use that instead
- Side note - it feels a bit weird to me that `get_wind_direction` only returns "north", "south", "east" and "west" if the angle is *exactly* 0, 180, 90 or 270 degrees - I'd say 89 degrees is more east than north-east
- While building a query string by hand works fine, it's often neater to use the `params` argument of `request.get`'s `params` options:

```py
requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', params={
    "q": city,
    "units": "metric",
    "appid": key
})
```

- Chained comparisons like `90 < angle and angle < 180` can be simplified to `90 < angle < 180`
- Different operating systems have different ways of separating the parts of a file path. For portability, it might be better to not provide the path as a single string, but instead use `Path` to combine the pieces like `Path(_current_path, 'icons')` instead of `f"{_current_path}\\icons"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A lot to learn. As to the image, never did anything like that yet and that's the only way it actually work, but now I am going to try to do it as you said. I kept class WeatherData as I am aiming to make this app a bit more useful, so I will add some extra features like next day weather prediction etc etc, but want to do it right way. Definitely will use your advice to use Path rather than path as string. Wind direction will be changed, more or less if wind is closer to value return south or west etc (89 will be closer to east ) just didn't work out how to do it yet.